# Dúvida com DependencyService xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Fiz a criação de um projeto apenas android usando o xamarin
Problema : problema neste ponto não reconhece DependencyService

Uma interface :

```html
namespace Projeto.Xamarin.Android
{
    public interface IConfig
    {
        string DiretorioDB { get; }
        ISQLitePlatform Plataforma { get; }
    }
}
```

Configuração :

```html
namespace Projeto.Xamarin.Android
{ 
   public class Config : IConfig
    {

        private string diretorioDB;
        private ISQLitePlatform plataforma;


        public string DiretorioDB
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(diretorioDB))
                {
                    diretorioDB = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                }
                return diretorioDB;
            }
        }

        public ISQLitePlatform Plataforma
        {
            get
            {
                if (plataforma == null)
                {
                    plataforma = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
                }
                return plataforma;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataAcess:

```html
namespace XFEmpleados
{
    class DataAccess : IDisposable
    {
      private SQLiteConnection connection;

        public DataAccess()
        {
            //problema neste ponto não reconhece DependencyService
            //   var config = DependencyService.Get<IConfig>();
            //   connection = new SQLiteConnection(config.) 
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dois pontos.

- A interface IConfig deve estar no projeto principal (Portable), e não no Projeto Android
- Você tem que colocar uma anotação na classe Config, dai vai ficar assim:

> ```
> [assembly: Dependency(typeof(Config))]
> namespace Projeto.Xamarin.Android
> {
>     public class Config : IConfig
>     {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```